# JavaDoc feedback

Tags: java, javadoc

This is the javadoc I've written, is this the proper way to document and if so what are ways to improve my documentation?

```
/**
 * Description: with the dna sequence provided the each letter will be check if 
*  the strand is a C. If the strand is C it will keep the amount and record of how many are 
     *  in the Sequence  
     * pre: needs the dna sequence 
     * @param string 
     * post: the amount of c in the sequence 
     * @returns int 
     */
```

I understand that there are multiple formats to document.

Comment: There's no point putting `@returns int`. The method signature already specifies the *type* of the return value. The @returns clause should describe the *meaning* of the return value. Similarly @param. Also prefixing your javadoc with "Description:" is redundant.

Comment: You cannot place arbitrary text between @param and @returns.  And your @param has the same defect that khelwood pointed out with your @return.  It needs to be `@param` followed by *the name of the parameter* followed by a meaningful description of the parameter.  Remember, the audience of your documentation is developers who are not familiar with your code.  Help them by describing what the method accepts and what it does.  Also, see [How to write Doc Comments](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html).

Answer (score 2):

Original

```java
/**
 * Description: with the dna sequence provided the each letter will be check if 
*  the strand is a C. If the strand is C it will keep the amount and record of how many are 
     *  in the Sequence  
     * pre: needs the dna sequence 
     * @param string 
     * post: the amount of c in the sequence 
     * @returns int 
     */
```

Modified

1. You don't need to prefix the description with 'Description'. It's expected that what you're about to write describes the intended use of the function. I can definitely see why you would inertially think to include this though.
2. The grammar can be improved; 'the each letter will be check if', doesn't make this feel like a professional javadoc. If english isn't your first language, great job learning a 2nd one! We can improve this!
3. I could be wrong but it kind of feels like you might come from a QA/Test background due to description/pre/post. If so, great job making this descriptive, this encapsulates everything you need, but the formatting is a bit off. We can fix this!
4. String isn't a descriptive parameter, maybe call it something like 'sequence'.

```java
/**
 * Calculates the occurrences of the DNA strand 'C' in the sequence provided.  
 * 
 * @param sequence the sequence of DNA which may or may not include 
 *        one or more occurrences of the expected 'C' DNA. 
 * @return the total sum of occurrences for 'C', if any. Zero may be returned. 
 */
```

Comment: Not quite correct.  It should be `@return total sum of occurrences for 'C', if any. Zero may be returned`.  It’s @return (singular), not @returns, and the type is not supposed to follow it.  @return is only followed by a description.

Comment: Wow how did I miss that, thank you so much for pointing this out. Admittedly I haven't been doing a lot of java lately (sad times), so I really appreciate this. Thank you.

Comment: @VGR If I remember correctly, both `@return` and `@returns` are correct.

Comment: @MCEmperor I have never seen any mention it, and it’s not mentioned in [the standard doclet spec](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html).